# plist launchagent script not starting

Tags: plist

I know there are about a thousand of these kinds of questions on PLIST-files out there (which in itself should tell Apple that they went completely wrong with this one) but I have not found an answer yet that works for me.

what I could do with one line in crontab now needs an xml-file that I can't get to run properly.

The plist file looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.ll.dbcopy</string>
   <key>Program</key>
   <string>/Users/MyName/backup/dbcopy.sh</string>
   <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
   <dict>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
   </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It's placed in `/Library/LaunchAgents`

If I try to run it with `sudo launchctl start com.ll.dbcopy` it says

`error no such process`

I can run the program it points to just fine.

Any ideas why it fails?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ever comes across this problem, you need to launchctl load the plist before you try to run it. You get the "no such process" because launchctl doesn't find the plist in the array of loaded plist scripts. You're actually not starting the file (which would be more logical since "start" is explicitly used for testing, according to Apple's MAN-pages for launchctl), you're pointing to the reference in the list of plists and starting that.

So if you make a change to the plist and want to "start" again, you need to unload and then load again.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else coming across this question might be typing:

```
launchctl start ...
```

when what they want is:

```
launchctl load ...
```

Comment: That's what my answers already says although arguably yours is shorter and thereby better :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, which did lead me to the solution, but didn't quite understand what you were saying at first.